# Read Jfrog Artifact's X-Ray Report from CLI

Tags: artifact, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray

I have to read Jfrog Artifact X-ray report.
On console the report can be seen under Artifactory-> Artifacts-> (Choose specific Artifact) ->X-ray

I want to read the same report from CLI for which i am not able to get the cli command.
Can someone please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a build result using Xray's [Build Summary REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Xray+REST+API#XrayRESTAPI-BuildSummary), and reports using one of the [Reports REST APIs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Xray+REST+API#XrayRESTAPI-REPORTS).

JFrog CLI does not currently support getting the report from Xray. You will however be provided with a scan summary if you trigger the scan using JFrog CLI's [Build Scan](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-ScanningaPublishedBuild) command.

Comment: Yeah i can get the results through REST API'S but i have to use a CLI command to get the report. The problem with the Build scan command is that it is not providing the actual X-Ray report of the artifacts. Even though the X-ray report of artifacts are severe in nature, build scan is not reflecting that

Comment: You can use the [JFrog CLI cURL command](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-RunningcUrl) to use the REST APIs. Note however that the command is designed to work against Artifactory so you might need to make some workarounds in the config url

Comment: @ChaitanyaVats Did it work for you, could you pls share the API request that worked ?